# How to add the Ubuntu One indicator in Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu-one, lubuntu

I have only managed to find guides for 12.04 and am needing a dock applet to show status of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is support in LXDE for using the indicators system of Ubuntu, you can simply install the `indicator-sync` package, and then log out and back in.

If not, you can add something to the start-up applications list to run `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --minimized --with-icon` on log-in, which will put an icon in the system tray. This will require having the control panel application running at all times however, as well as the background sync process.

These are the steps that should be followed: Menu > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession > Autostart > Enter: `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --minimized --with-icon` in the rectangle > press "+ Add". Restart your computer and you will see Ubuntu One indicator.

Comment: Thanks. The indicator-sync is already installed and doesn't put anything in the tray, but the other command, followed by a `&` works well and I'll adapt it for automatic launching.

Comment: @dobey: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me in Lubuntu 13.10. These are the steps that should be followed: Menu-Preferences-Default applications for LXSession-Autostart-Write "ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --minimized --with-icon" in the rectangle and then press bottom named "+ Add". Restart your computer and you will see Ubuntu One indicator.